# OpenMDAO v0.13: GUI Error after Installation

Tags: openmdao

I have recieved error when I intend to start GUI as indicated Installation video.
Thanks everyone

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,
Here is the video / @9:46:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5oWyY_L4Vxc

and Here is the my error message:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 1086 tests in 335.301s

    OK (SKIP=16)
    (openmdao-0.13.0)oneral@oneral:~/openmdao-0.13.0$ openmdao gui
    usage: openmdao [-h] [-v]
                    {list_testhosts,docs,test,test_arch,view_case_data} ...
    openmdao: error: invalid choice: 'gui' (choose from 'list_testhosts', 'docs', 'test', 'test_arch', 'view_case_data')
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your interest in OpenMDAO.

The reason that the GUI will not start for you using 0.13.0 is that it was discontinued after 0.10.3.2, as noted here:

http://openmdao.org/openmdao-version-0-12-0/

The video is from 0.10.3.2 and is marked as "out of date" for that reason.  However, if you still want to try out the GUI, 0.10.3.2 is still available for download here:

http://openmdao.org/downloads/archive/